# Size adjustments for Panel control in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a Panel control on my winform which will display multiple panels inside that. For each inner panel I am setting its height. But some has less content to display some has more.

```
Panel hrvPanel = new Panel();
ArrayList hrvColl = pnlColl ; //Panel collection list gets from a Method            
if(hrvColl.Count == 0)
            return;
        int splits = 0;
        for(int p= hrvColl.Count-1;p>=0;p--)
        {
            Panel hrv = hrvColl[p] as Panel;
            hrv.Height = 150;
            hrvPanel.Controls.Add(hrv);

            //Adding splliter
            if(splits < hrvColl.Count - 1)
            {
                Splitter splitGrid = new Splitter();
                splitGrid.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                hrvPanel.Controls.Add(splitGrid);
                splits++;
            }
        }
  hrvPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
```

How to adjust the height of each inner panel based on its content size? I tried setting hrv.AutoSize to true,then I can see only the last panel And hrv.Dock = Top but the result is same.

Comment: If the outer Panel has `Autosize = true` you __will__ be able to see all inner Panels. If you don't, you have got some settings wrong. Make sure no unwnated settings of Dock and Anchor are used in the inner Panels. - It would also be simple to write a function to find out the Max of Top+Height over all inner Panels, but that really is not needed!

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the outer `Panel` has `Autosize = true` you **will** be able to see all inner `Panels`. Promise.

If you don't, you have got some settings wrong. Make sure no unwanted settings of `Dock` and `Anchor` are used in the inner `Panels`.

It is also very simple to write code to find out the maximum of `Top + Height` over all inner Panels:

```
int max = 0;
foreach (Control ctl in panelOuter.Controls) 
   if (ctl.Top + ctl.Height > max) max = ctl.Top + ctl.Height;
panelOuter.Height = max + 3;  // add the default margin!
```

This may be useful if you only want to set the `Height` and leave the `Width` as it is..other than that: The `AutoSize` property will do its job!

Answer (score 0):

This is where WPF overcomes Winform, you probably can't do this automatically in Winforms. But you may have a work around like this-

> Create an extended panel class that should know its preferred height

```
class ExPanel : Panel
{
    public int PreferredHeight
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public ExPanel(int preferredHeight)
        : base()
    {
        PreferredHeight = preferredHeight;
    }
}
```

and then you can use this class as-

```
ExPanel hrvPanel = new ExPanel(150);
        System.Collections.ArrayList hrvColl = pnlColl; //Panel collection list gets from a Method            
        if (hrvColl.Count == 0)
            return;
        int splits = 0;
        for (int p = hrvColl.Count - 1; p >= 0; p--)
        {
            ExPanel hrv = hrvColl[p] as ExPanel;
            hrv.Height = hrv.PreferredHeight;
            hrvPanel.Controls.Add(hrv);

            //Adding splliter
            if (splits < hrvColl.Count - 1)
            {
                Splitter splitGrid = new Splitter();
                splitGrid.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                hrvPanel.Controls.Add(splitGrid);
                splits++;
            }
        }
        hrvPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
```

it's just an workaround to achieve your target, if you don't want to manage the height for your every panel.

Comment: Is it not possible to adjust height of each panel based on its content size?

Comment: @M.K, it is and you have to do it manually. You have to set it manually while creating the panel. Also for some R&D, you can check what is the PreferredSize of the panels before adding them in parent panel.

Comment: PreferredSize is showing 0,0 always. I am setting iheight manually now. But same value for all panels. Because I don't know how many panels will be created.

Comment: Just try this approach, if acceptable you can use it.